# How do I combine these 3 powershell commands into a single line?

Tags: email, powershell, exchange-server, powershell-3.0, exchange-server-2010

I need to select three pieces of data from an email contact, and place them into columns, (export-csv style columns).

I'm unsure how to "split" the output from the following commands.

**Get the primary SMTP address**

```
ForEach ($address in Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Select EmailAddresses) {$address.EmailAddresses | Where {$_.Prefix -match"smtp" -and $_.IsPrimaryAddress -eq $true} | Select AddressString }
```

**Get all smtpAddresses** (hopefully omit the primary)

```
ForEach ($address in Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Select EmailAddresses) {$address.EmailAddresses | Where {$_.Prefix -match "SMTP" } | Select AddressString }
```

**Get the X500 address**

```
ForEach ($address in Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Select EmailAddresses) {$address.EmailAddresses | Where {$_.Prefix -match "x400" } | Select AddressString }
```

How do I join them into a single column?

Answer (score 2):

I would most likely do something like this

```powershell
$results =  Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | ForEach-Object{
    $props = @{
        Name = $_.alias
        Primary = $_ | Select -ExpandProperty emailaddresses | 
                Where {$_.Prefix -cmatch "SMTP" -and $_.IsPrimaryAddress -eq $true} | 
                Select-Object -ExpandProperty AddressString 
        Secondary = $_ | Select -ExpandProperty emailaddresses | 
                Where {$_.Prefix -cmatch "smtp" } | 
                Select-Object -ExpandProperty AddressString 
        x400 = $_ | Select -ExpandProperty emailaddresses | 
                Where {$_.Prefix -match "x400" } |  
                Select-Object -ExpandProperty AddressString   
    }

    New-Object –TypeName PSObject -Property $props
} 

$results | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation C:\temp\export.csv
```

I had coded this in ISE using `[pscustomobject]` on my machine but my exchange server is only PowerShell version 2.0. Updated to use `New-Object` with the properties of the emails as you have broken them down and a mailbox alias to help identify the output.

You also need to use `-cmatch` since the primary and secondary are associated to the case of the string "SMTP"

If you have at least version 3.0 PowerShell at your disposal this would work as well

```powershell
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | ForEach-Object{
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name = $_.alias
        Primary = $_ | Select -ExpandProperty emailaddresses | 
                Where {$_.Prefix -cmatch "SMTP" -and $_.IsPrimaryAddress -eq $true} | 
                Select-Object -ExpandProperty AddressString 
        Secondary = $_ | Select -ExpandProperty emailaddresses | 
                Where {$_.Prefix -cmatch "smtp" } | 
                Select-Object -ExpandProperty AddressString 
        x400 = $_ | Select -ExpandProperty emailaddresses | 
                Where {$_.Prefix -match "x400" } |  
                Select-Object -ExpandProperty AddressString   
    }
} | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation C:\temp\export.csv
```

**Side note** about Secondary addresses.

If you have more than one the output might be better if it was delimited with another character.

```
        Secondary = ($_ | Select -ExpandProperty emailaddresses | 
                Where {$_.Prefix -cmatch "smtp" } | 
                Select-Object -ExpandProperty AddressString) -join ";"
```

That code would work in place now and just be harmless if there was only one secondary anyway.